# If Loop For Full Column Using Len

Tags: vba, loops

I want to do an If statement that measures the amount of characters in an autofilter column and if the amount of characters (Len) = 9 or 12, I want it to go to the first column and change the name of the cell on that row to "CLO". I want this to run for the full column (column M & N). How should I go about that?

```
    Dim count As Integer, myRange As Range, rng As Range
Dim RealRng As Range

Set myRange = Columns("M:M")
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
Set RealRng = ActiveSheet.Range("M2:M+" & count)
For Each rng In RealRng
    If Len(rng) = 9 Or Len(rng) = 12 Then
        rng.Offset(0, -12) = "Bond"
    End If
Next rng
```

Comment: What language? Is there any actual code to go with the question?

Comment: VBA macro, and I guess if you need to see what i'm doing. I've just added code that searches the autofilter for words that ocntain "MBS" but what i'm describing is similar but quite different

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo that will loop through a filtered range, test for length, and change the next column if length 9 or 12.

You'll need to adapt for your purposes:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim filteredRng As Range, rng As Range

    Set filteredRng = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each rng In filteredRng
        If Len(rng) = 9 Or Len(rng) = 12 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1) = "CLO"
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Alex, I really appreciate the help. This really seems exactly what I want it to do. I just needed assistance in one aspect of the code you posted. Is there anyway you could set filteredRng to something that would figure out how many rows there are in column M and select M2:the end and then proceed the formula to go on from there? Here's what I've tried to edit the code to...you can see it in my updated OP

Comment: `Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)` and then `Set filteredRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. Try that...